# Presenting screen in Teams for Android: Screen goes blank when I move hand near camera

Tags: screen, camera, screen-sharing, microsoft-teams

I have Microsoft Teams installed on my Samsung tablet. I often share my tablet screen in Teams meetings. When I move my hand near the tablet screen, the screen goes blank (temporarily).

Why does this happen? Is it some sort of functionality for quickly stopping presenting in an emergency?

Comment: The proximity sensor is usually a led + sensor that detects the reflected light of that led. On most devices you can see the led flashing while on a call and looking at the device through an camera of a second smartphone or digital camera. It is usually located right above the screen. May be you can "hack" the proximity sensor by sticking a small perfectly black patch on it so that it can't detect any reflections.

Answer (score 2):

You're triggering the proximity sensor. Those are located somewhere above the screen or in the notch, depending on the design of your device.

The purpose of proximity sensor is to disable screen and touchscreen inputs when you're talking with your phone next to your head. It prevents accidentally interacting with the touchscreen with your ear.

It's mostly useful for regular phone calls, but internet calling software can also make use of it.

Your screen sharing is probably still in progress while you do that, it only blanks your display.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it blanks out the screen for the other attendees in the meeting too.